# how to automatically upload the code on Github to FTP server

Tags: git, github, ftp

I used to work on Github at company, usually when I commit some change on Github, push it , then the change parts will automatically upload to the remote FTP server so I can view it on the web without download all the code on Git then push it to FTP by myself again.

Does anyone know how to do that? Now I want to set up this for my own project, but I only know how to push code to Git, don't know how to automatically upload the stuff on Git to Server.

I heard someone says use Git-FTP, but I download it , totally don't know how to use it. Hope someone can explain it to me or any tools you know.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Anyone knows how to upload change parts of the code on Git to FTP server automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do that, without using an external software, is to use a `post-commit` hook that updates a repo (on another server for example), then uploads the files to the FTP.